# Why doesn't Tomcat Server have latest HTML updates?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat, backbone.js

I'am trying to run this [project](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jax-cellar) on my local host.

I followed these [instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/j2ee/scenarios/running_webproject.html) on how to launch a dynamic web project on Tomcat Server.

Everything works and when I run the application, I see this which is correct [image]

Now I'am trying to play around with the code a bit. I located the html code that corresponds to the new wine page - /WebContent/tpl/wine-details.html

I changed the country label to show states instead.[image]

However when I re run the web application on the Tomcat Server, the label still says country.

Does anyone know what the issue is? I made sure to save the file. What I also found interesting was there were two copies of this file, in backbone-jax-cellar and backbone-jax-cellar-master. I made sure that both copies contained the states label.

Comment: Try running your server in debug mode, that usually enables hot deploy of resources

Comment: @NickVanderhoven Just tried it. There's a bunch of system and config messages but that doesn't help me with this issue.

Comment: @NickVanderhoven Actually when I visit the URL in Chome, it shows the updated label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's having this issue still, I recommend just visiting the URL in a web browser. I used Chrome and everything is showing up fine.

I think the problem here is that Eclipse is somehow caching the html page and doesn't update it when it runs the web app